# Xamarin.Forms to ESP8266 Wifi moduleConnection

Tags: raspberry-pi, esp8266, arduino, android, microsoft-windows-iot

Am build new application for ESP8266.
Then how can i connect my xamarin.forms application to esp8266
any reference and documentation for this.
Already referred WIFIManager library in android many of issues

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/index ....... maybe set up a web server on the ESP8266